# Having trouble getting callbacks to work with module mixins

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account

  default_scope where(:account_id => Account.current_account.id)
  before_validation :add_current_account

  private

  def add_current_account
    self.account = Account.current_account
  end

end
```

I tried pulling out the parts after the `belongs_to: account` so I can re-use that stuff in other models.

I tried using the approach described here:

http://blog.waxman.me/extending-your-models-in-rails-3

But for some reason, I kept getting errors like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `before_validation' for Multitenant:Module

NameError: undefined local variable or method `add_current_account' for #<Class:0x007f9b06d47760>
```

Am I missing something?  This should be a regular ruby mixin right?  Seems like rails is getting in the way but I'm not sure sure why or how.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.